# XCRemoteSwiftPackageReference .git suffix constantly changing in project.pbxproj

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, appcode

On our team, pull requests were often raised with changes similar to the following

[image: project.pbxproj diff]

(or sometimes they would change back, that is, remove the `.git`)

This was causing a lot of noise in PRs but we were unable figure out the cause of the change.

Comment: I have also been experiencing this lately using only XCode (no AppCode). I can't wrap my head around the reason why this is happening tho

Answer (score 1):

We (much) later discovered that this was happening because a member of the team was using AppCode without our knowledge. It is also a known issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-21297/AppCode-messes-up-the-xcodeproj-project-pbxproj-file-and-introdu

Comment: Oh, interesting. This is happening for us also. I'll ask the team if they're using AppCode. 

Comment: This has been occurring with my team as well. No one is using AppCode though. Wonder what is causing this...

Answer (score 0):

Another potential source is the `Xcodeproj` library which is used by many tools, including `fastlane`.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/882